# SQL GROUP BY query showing data if column value has changed

Tags: php

I am running an SQL Query on my table and grouping by 2 columns

`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY source, calltype`

I've set `$source = '';` outside the loop and then inside my loop, I am checking

```
$source = '';
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM billing_calldata GROUP BY source, calltype;");
while($result = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    if($source != $result["source"]) {
        $source = $result["source"];
        echo 'data';
    }
}
```

and if it has changed, I want to display certain data

Using the above, its not displaying my data inside the `if`

Comment: _Using the above, its not displaying my data inside the if..._ Well there is no code that is trying to _display_ anything

Comment: @B001ᛦ i know that, but the data displays inside the if

Comment: Can you show the code for the loop as well (or at least how you fetch the data from the SQL statement)

Comment: code updated, i basically want to show some data if the `$result["source"]` has changed

Comment: So what does `$result["source"]` actually contain? Add a var_dump before the if to verify.

Comment: Could you show us some sample data for the table?

Comment: `$result["source"]` will only ever contain `A` or `B`

Comment: I think $result["source"] = '' therefore condition fails can you add elese and print something and check.

Comment: `$result["source"]` is being set